# Zend Framework 2 - jquery modal popup issue

Tags: jquery-ui, zend-framework2

I have a view `showform.phtml` that is loaded into a div via jquery `dialog`. In the view I am loading a javascript with a `$(form).submit()` listener. The problem is, the javascript is never loaded. I have tried a couple of different methods, including `$this->headScript()->appendScript(script)`, `$this->headScript()->appendScript(file)`. I even tried just including the script in the layout and index view so that it was sure to be available... but the popup never fires it.

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I am using `setTerminal(true)` on the form view... but I don't know what the alternative is.

Anyone have any advice on troubleshooting? Or any experience with this issue?

thanks

EDIT :
This is sample javasctipt that loads in the index.phtml view

```
$(function()
{    
    $("form#News").submit(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/main/manage/validateajax',
            data: $('form#News').serialize(),
            success: 'success'
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

The body of the view is a div that showform.phtml loads into
showform creates a form called #News.

When I insert the js code into the body of showform, it works. When I append this to the headScript, it does not work.

Comment: It's logic : **setTerminal(true)** is to don't load the layout and your headScript helper is in the layout. Try to print your JS inside the view or include it into the main js (whose already loaded when you call the modal)

Comment: I tried that, I even had it loaded in the layout, but it seems to be invisible to the view. (or the view seems invisible to the js). I did not try just loading into the body of the view... I will give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: So, it works if I insert the script into the body of the view. First of all, that is not very good form, but mostly I shouldn't have to do that! I am certain there are apps that use js and modal popups. What gives? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Ideally what `validateajax` action should do is to give back a JSON-Response with an array of error-messages - empty json if no error messages are present. Work with JSONModel in that case. There's no really need to return a real HTML View just for validation purposes.

Comment: My problem is that the the javascript listener does not "hear" the view. The only way I get it to work is if the javascript is in the body of the view, which is not good convention.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a solution for you.

**Requirement**: scripts of your modal view have to be already loaded (for example inside the *application.js*)

```
$("#loadModalBtn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#modalContainer").load(url, function(){  // that's the point

        var urlForm = $("form#News").attr("action");

        $("form#News").submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: urlForm,
                data: $('form#News').serialize(),
                success: 'success'
            });
            return false;
        });
    }).dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
    }); 
});
```